# NodeJS : Rotate a base64 image and save it

Tags: node.js, canvas, base64

I want to make a function to rotate at 90° an base64 image. I tried to use Image and Canvas but it returns Error.

Here is the Code :

```
exports.Test64 = (req, res, next) => {
 console.log("TEST UPS")
  upsres.find().then(
    (ups) => {
      console.log('YES');
      console.log(ups[0].b64Image); // it works but after i don't think
      var image = new Image();
      var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      image.src = ups[0].b64Image;
      canvas.width = image.height;
      canvas.height = image.width;
      ctx.rotate(-90 * Math.PI / 180);
      ctx.translate(-canvas.heigt,0);
      ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
      dataURL= canvas.toDataURL();
      console.log(dataURL);
      res.status(200).json(dataURL);
      );
    }
  ).catch(
    (error) => {
      res.status(400).json({
        error:'Not Working'
      });
    }
  );
};
```

Someone have an answer why it doesn't work ? :)

Thanks to everyone

Comment: Please me what comes error ?

Comment: {
        error:'Not Working'
      }

Comment: ok, Thank you, I am checking

Comment: Replace this error:'Not Working' with error:error to see what is the actual error.

Comment: it marks { error :{} }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use jimp libray to get rotate image.
Please use following code

```
   var Jimp = require('jimp');
    const base64str ="R0lG"//
     const buf = Buffer.from(base64str, 'base64');
    const image = await Jimp.read(buf);

   // rotate Function having a rotation as 90
    image.rotate(90).getBase64(Jimp.MIME_JPEG, function (err, src) {
    console.log("rb is \n")
    console.log(src);
  })
```

Comment: Not working it's not async function, and without await Jimp.read. image.rotate.. doesn't work)

Comment: you make async function if no problem you

Comment: exports.Test64 =  async (req, res, next) => { });

Comment: jimp is full of problem, (memory leak, do not manage big file) maybe another solution should be provided time that they fix their issues

Comment: All who find this thread, please note - Jimp changes the dimensions of your image on rotation quietly. There is not a method in the library I have found that removes this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
exports.Testups = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    let ups = await upsres.find()
    const base64str = ups[0].b64Image;
    const buf = Buffer.from(base64str, 'base64');
    let image = await Jimp.read(buf);

    // rotate Function having a rotation as 90
    image.rotate(-90).getBase64(Jimp.MIME_PNG, function (err, src) {
    res.status(200).json(src);
    })
  }
  catch (e) { }
};
```

That's Working :)

Comment: you can call Jimp function  without await  ?